# Saving File conversion to variable instead of physical location

Tags: c#, .net, variables, memorystream, converters

I'm trying out to use the XML - Mind converter https://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/ to convert some xsl-fo to an rtf and this works well . Just to be clear this is nothing specific to the conveter or its functionality but just a clarification I would like to get which is why I am asking this on stack overflow .

So I have the following code (that was obtained from some documentation)

```
string foFilePath = @"D:\Temp\test.fo";
string ourPutFilePath = @"D:\Temp\test.rtf";


                Converter converter = new Converter();
                converter.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Rtf;
                converter.OutputEncoding = "windows-1252";
                converter.ImageResolution = 120;


                converter.SetInput(foFilePath);
                converter.SetOutput(ourPutFilePath);
                
                converter.Convert();
```

What happens here is quite simple Reads a file from the input path and stores the converted file in the specified output . The question I would like to clarify here is , wheather it would be possible to store this content that is being saved in the file out put path within a variable as well to may be do some processing during the application runtime ?

Maybe I can use the `MemoryStream` for it ? I'm just not sure how to do it and would really appreciate some help here.

I understand that I can always read it back from the file output path but I am looking for something better than that as saving the file to a certain location may not always be possible in my case

EDIT :- The converter.SetOutput() method allows 3 overloads in the parameters

1. String fileName
2. Stream stream
3. TextWriter writer

Comment: As long as the `Converter` doesnt allow you to pass a `Stream` as an argument for the `.SetOutput` method - I doubt that would be possible. Does it have any other overloads?

Comment: We would need to see the code inside the converter class.  The method takes a string.  If the code took a stream then you can use a MemoryStream.  But right now the code writes directly to a file using the filename.

Comment: See starting a bottom of page 10 of the manual.  You can create your own converter that inherits the base class so you can add you own methods.  See link : https://www.xmlmind.com/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/progress?id=jmpDfFt3LsOiJRpAIDEk1Q4FORd-0quu39uP5Ra9eKQ,

Comment: @jdweng that page is unreachable

Comment: @Alex the converter.SetOutput() has 3 overloads . That is for a path , Stream and a TextWriter anything usable with the Stream ?

Comment: if it does have overload that accepts a stream, you could probably just pass a `new MemoryStream()`

Comment: @Alex you could for the for the set output method but I'm not sure how that will get the content in a variable .. Any idea on that ?

Comment: do you want the content as a string?

Comment: @Alex yes please

Comment: Updated URL : https://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/_distrib/dotnet/doc/user/userguide.pdf

Comment: Thanks @jdweng  for the updates link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you need the output as a string you could try doing something like this

```
      string content;
      using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
          Converter converter = new Converter();
          converter.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Rtf;
          converter.OutputEncoding = "windows-1252";
          converter.ImageResolution = 120;
          converter.SetInput(foFilePath);
          converter.SetOutput(writer);
          converter.Convert();
          stream.Position = 0;
          content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
      }
```

I'm not sure about the Encoding though, and if the `Convert()` uses a different encoding this might not work